# Assigning name to AWS SageMaker Training job

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

This may be a very basic question (I imagine it is)

```
estimator = PyTorch(entry_point='train.py',
                   source_dir = 'code',
                    role = role,
                   framework_version = '1.5.0',
                   py_version = 'py3',
                   instance_count = 2,
                   instance_type = 'ml.g4dn.2xlarge',
                   hyperparameters={"epochs": 2,
                                     "num_labels": 46,
                                     "backend": "gloo",    
                                    },
                   profiler_config=profiler_config,
                    debugger_hook_config=debugger_hook_config,
                    rules=rules
                   )
```

I declare my estimator as above, and put this into training using fit().
I have done several of these on my sagemaker, and there are several training jobs in the aws training job log.
But they all appear in the form 'pytorch-training-2021 ....'. 
Is there anyway I could declare the name of the training job like 'custom-model-xgboost-ver1' ?
I thought it would be possible as one of the parameter of estimator, but i couldn't find it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `fit()` you can pass this parameter `job_name=yourJobName`

Answer (score 4):

You can use the below snippet as an example to do that using `estimator.fit()`

```
from sagemaker.pytorch import PyTorch

estimator = PyTorch(entry_point='mnist.py',
                    role=role,
                    py_version='py3',
                    framework_version='1.8.0',
                    instance_count=2,
                    instance_type='ml.c5.2xlarge',
                    hyperparameters={
                        'epochs': 1,
                        'backend': 'gloo'
                    })
estimator.fit('training': inputs, job_name='Name')
```